# Ayuda con problema CS1586 visual studia junto a MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

No entiendo porque me da error CS1586, especificamente cuando digo `new string[]`

```
class ConsultaMySQL
    {
        private MySqlConnection conexion = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost; database=thepacioli; Uid=root; pwd=Valentin_01; Sslmode=none");
        private DataSet ds;

        private DataTable MostrarDatos()        
        {
          conexion.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select *from usuario", conexion);
            MySqlDataAdapter ad = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            ds = new DataSet();
            ad.Fill(ds, "tabla");
            conexion.Close();
            return ds.Tables["tabla"];            
        }

        private DataTable Buscar(string nombre)
        {
            conexion.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(string.Format("select *from usuario where nombre like '%(0)$'",nombre), conexion);
            MySqlDataAdapter ad = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            ds = new DataSet();
            ad.Fill(ds, "tabla");
            conexion.Close();
            return ds.Tables["tabla"];
        }

        public bool Insertar(string id, string nombre, string segundo_nombre, string apellido, string sexo)
        {
            conexion.Open();

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(string.Format("Insert into usuario values (0), '(1)', '(2)', '(3)', '(4)'", new string[](id, nombre, segundo_nombre, apellido, sexo)), conexion);
            int filasafectadas = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conexion.Clone();

            if (filasafectadas > 0) return true;
            else return false;
        }

        public bool Eliminar(string id)
        {
            conexion.Open();

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(string.Format("delete from usuario where id={0}", id), conexion);
            int filasafectadas = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conexion.Clone();

            if (filasafectadas > 0) return true;
            else return false;
        }

        public bool Actualizar(string id, string nombre, string segundo_nombre, string apellido, string sexo)
        {
            conexion.Open();

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(string.Format("update usuario set nombre={0}, segundo_nombre={1}, apellido={2}, sexo={3} where id={4}", new string[] (nombre, segundo_nombre, apellido, sexo, id)), conexion);
            int filasafectadas = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conexion.Clone();

            if (filasafectadas > 0) return true;
            else return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ese error está perfectamente explicado en la [documentación de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1586). No puedes inicializar un array sin especificar su tamaño:

```
int[] a = new int[];   // CS1586  
// debes usar lo siguiente:
int[] b = new int[5];
```

Por cierto, en el código que muestras no aparece `new string[]` por ningún lado, y además este error no tiene absolutamente nada que ver con MySql.

**Editado**

Ahora veo cómo lo estás usando. En tu código tienes esto:

```
new string[](id, nombre, segundo_nombre, apellido, sexo)
```

Estás intentando inicializar un array de string *inline*. Para ello, debes usar `{}` en lugar de `()`:

```
new string[] { id, nombre, segundo_nombre, apellido, sexo }
```

Comment: Si está new string []

Comment: Dónde está la línea de comando MySqlCommand, más adelante esta un string.format y más adelante el new string []. Todo eso en la misma línea. En todo el código hay dos new string []

Comment: @JatnielNuñez vale, hice una búsqueda y no lo veía. Edito mi respuesta para explicarte tu problema.

Comment: Dios como no me di cuenta. GRACIAS, de veras, Gracias